# Getting error outputs due to using ios::sync_with_stdio(0);cin.tie(0);cout.tie(0); in the code

Tags: c++, c++17

In this code below the **ios::sync_with_stdio(0);cin.tie(0);cout.tie(0);** statement seems to be causing some problems. I tried with different variation like **ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);cin.tie(0);cout.tie(0);** or **ios::sync_with_stdio(0),cin.tie(0),cout.tie(0);**

For these test cases :

5

5

apple

15

schtschurowskia

6

polish

5

tryst

3

cry

The expected output should be :

YES

NO

YES

NO

YES

But due to this line **ios::sync_with_stdio(0);cin.tie(0);cout.tie(0);** I'm getting

NO

YES

YES

YES

YES

Note that: these results I'm getting from online judges but in reality I'm getting the output as expected but **all at once after finishing all my test cases**, which was unexpected. So my question is why this delay is happening and how come the online judges are giving a wrong output.

```
#include "bits/stdc++.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
ios::sync_with_stdio(0);cin.tie(0);cout.tie(0);
int t;
cin >> t;
while(t-- > 0){
    int n, cnt = 0, rem = 0;
    cin >> n;
    char str[n];
    scanf("%s", str);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if (str[i] != 'a' && str[i] != 'e' && str[i] != 'i' && str[i] != 'o' && str[i] != 'u'){
        cnt++;
        rem = max(cnt, rem);
    }
    else
        cnt = 0;
    }
    cout << (rem < 4 ? "YES" : "NO") << '\n';
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't use these lines at all. Using them will cause you all kinds of trouble like this.

Comment: You asked for things to be unsynchronized. They are now unsynchronized and you are complaining about what?

Comment: `#include "bits/stdc++.h"
using namespace std;` - Please don't *ever* do either of those.

Comment: `char str[n];` is bad because 1. This is non-standard VLA (Variable-Length Array) 2. There are no space for the terminating null-character, so the `scanf()` will cause out-of-range write.

Comment: @JesperJuhl it's mainly for competetive programming. So using them saves a lot of time

Comment: @NazmusSakibSibly That's about the worst reason I've ever heard. Ditch "competitive programming" - it'll only teach you bad habits/practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're explicitly unsyncing the standard C++ streams and the standard C streams, but then mixing them in your code. Switch the `scanf` with `cin`.